# Error when adding 'cardView' in xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

The error I get is:

```
Failed to find style with id 0x7fff0020 in current theme
```

here is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.echodevteam.isaac.echo_simplyawesome.Login"
android:background="#FFF">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my theme:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="EchoTheme">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

It's already in my gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
```

I want to know how to fix this error. Since I'm new to android, I beg to please be specific. Thank you!

Comment: Where is EchoTheme defined? It seems you are missing its definition.

Comment: I have it defined in the folder 'styles.xml' and it's in 'styles.xml (v21)'. That's where I have EchoTheme defined.

Comment: Did you sync the project after you modified the gradle? also if you're on eclipse try re-opening your project

Comment: Yes sir. I did sync it after I was done editing the gradle. And I'm in Android Studio

Comment: Try changing the preview device in the xml editor or lowering the api